# Is there an easy way to make all text boxes across a WinForms app respond to certain keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: c#, winforms

For instance, I want all my text boxes to respond to Ctrl-A by selecting all text. I see several options:

- Add an event handler to all the text boxes that takes care of the keyboard shortcuts
- Subclass `TextBox` and replace all my text boxes with it
- Create a user control that wraps `TextBox` and replace all my text boxes with it

However all of these involve changing each and every text box in the app. Is there any sort of thing I could do globally to all text boxes via one action to accomplish this? I kind of doubt it but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask! (I mean, I suppose now that .NET is open source I could build a custom framework, but that's definitely overkill!)

Comment: You can intercept the keyboard at the form level using KeyPreview = true and then decide in a single place what to do with your textboxes

Comment: Hmm, there are still a lot of forms in the app, but that might simplify things a bit... I guess if I added a FormBase class which all my forms inherit from, I could unify all the handling there?

Comment: Then you can create a base form with the key handling and derive your forms from this one. But this will become really complex if different forms requires different key handling. You can raise yourself events from this base form and handle the differences

Comment: You can use a class that manages these procedure. Pass it the Form that is being opened, set the Form's `KeyPreview = true`, make it subscribe its `KeyDown` event and use a recursive method that finds out all the Form's `TextBoxBase` controls, then set  `TextBoxBase.HideSelection = false` and `TextBoxBase.SelectAll()` when the `CTRL-A` combination (or any other) is pressed. You can also use UI Automation, to detect when a Form is opened or closed, so you can add the same logic to a newly opened Form automatically, then remove the handler when it's detected that a Form is being closed .

Comment: Just change the project's target framework to 4.6.1 or higher.

Comment: If it's not just about Ctrl+A, as an option you can create a base form, in the base form override `ProcessCmdKey` and check if the active control is a `TextBox`, call its `SelectAll` method. In general, creating a new `TextBox` control is a better option and changing in all files of the solution is just a find/replace.

Answer (score 1):

I have a idea about that. The first step is get all controls of a control. Like this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control container)
{
    List<Control> controlList = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
    {
        controlList.AddRange(GetAllControls(c));
        controlList.Add(c);
    }
    return controlList;
}
```

You can improve this method to get just the TextBox's.

So, now you have all the TextBoxes that you want. You can add a event for each, something like that:

```
foreach( var textBox in textBoxList )
{
    textBox.KeyPress += MeyKeyPressEvento_KeyPress;
}
```

Or you can put that event int your form and select all TextBoxes.

I hope you can get a mindset with my answer. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically attach your events when you load your form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // iterate all controls on the form
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox textBox)
            {
                // attach your event's method
                textBox.KeyDown += OnKeyDown_SelectAllText;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnKeyDown_SelectAllText(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox) sender;
            textBox.SelectAll();
        }
    }

    // be sure to detach all events when done with form
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown_SelectAllText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```